# In R, How to separate data in a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following data matrix and I want to remove all of the data that is below the number 4. How would I go about doing this?

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    3    7
[4,]    4    8
```

Comment: So what do you want the shape of your output to be? Do you want to set values less than 4 to NA? Do you want to remove rows with values less than 4? Columns? What's the desired output here?

Comment: `mat[which(mat < 4)] <- NA`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
m <- matrix(1:8, ncol = 2)
m[m < 4] <- NA
#> m
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   NA    5
#[2,]   NA    6
#[3,]   NA    7
#[4,]    4    8
```

Comment: I don't think you need to convert it to a data frame, you can drop the call to "as.data.frame()"

Comment: Sure, and thanks for pointing this out. It works of course with a matrix as well. I didn't read the OP carefully. Now I revised the answer accordingly.